# ajax - javascript function to refresh a div

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, refresh

I'm trying to have a div refresh after a callback using ajax functions. Basically, I want **/includes/view_game/achievements.inc.php** to be reloaded in the div **#achievements_tab**. The callback (I didn't include it in codes below) works well and triggers the *AchievementRefresh* function found below (the opacity of the div changes to 0.5, but it remains like this and the refresh is not made).

Those two functions are used for another similar ajax refresh on my site that works well. So I tried to modify the code, but since it's for a slightly different purpose, maybe I have the wrong approach.

```
function AjaxPost(url, success_function) {
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp == null) {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support AJAX. You should upgrade it!")
        return
    }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = success_function;
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
}
```

This *AjaxPost* function is used in the other function below:

```
function AchievementRefresh() {
    div('achievements_tab').style.opacity = 0.5;
        div('highscore_pages').innerHTML = '<img src="'+site_url+'/images/loader.gif" />';

    AjaxPost(site_url+"/includes/view_game/achievements.inc.php?", '',
    function () {
        div('achievements_tab').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        div('achievements_tab').style.opacity = 1;
    }
    )
}
```

Comment: Err, where did you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `load`

```
$('#achievements_tab').load('/includes/view_game/achievements.inc.php');
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/load/

**Edit**
E.g.

```
function AchievementRefresh() {
    $('#achievements_tab').css('opacity', 0.5);
    $('#highscore_pages').html('<img src="'+site_url+'/images/loader.gif" />');

    $('#achievements_tab').load('/includes/view_game/achievements.inc.php')
        .success(function() {
            $('#achievements_tab').css('opacity', 1);
        });
}
```

Comment: Where do I insert this? Do I need to keep the *AjaxPost* function?

Comment: I've been able to make the refresh work using the following function, but I get mysql errors in the div (cant connect to database cause password = NO and lot of others), so I guess the refresh didn't include config.php and other files needed to make the code work properly. Any clues? Thanks!                                                                             AchievementRefresh() {
 div('achievements_tab').style.opacity = 0.5;
        $('#achievements_tab').load('/includes/view_game/achievements.inc.php');
        div('achievements_tab').style.opacity = 1;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       div('achievements_tab').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        div('achievements_tab').style.opacity = 1;
         }
  }
};`
```

Name and id is example.

Also, some changes:

```
AjaxPost(site_url+"/includes/view_game/achievements.inc.php");
var params= 'name'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'&id='+encodeURIComponent(id)
```

Parameters shouldn't be in URL.

```
xmlhttp.send(params);
```